# How to create a weekly task with GCP's Storage Transfer Service Python SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to create a weekly task with GCP's Storage Transfer Service Python SDK.

I'm writing code to deploy a Storage Transfer Service Job via GCP's official Python client library, and I'm currently having a problem:

1. When the schedule_start_date and schedule_end_date parameters in the schedule are the same, the job is issued as a one-time job.
   2、When the schedule_start_date and schedule_end_date parameters in schedule are different, the job issued is a daily job.

Now I want to send a weekly job, but no matter how to pass parameters to schedule, it automatically sends a daily job. how to deploy a weekly job?

The document I refer to is: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers?hl=zh-cn

```
transfer_job_request = storage_transfer.CreateTransferJobRequest({
    'transfer_job': {
        'project_id': project_id,
        'description': description,
        'status': storage_transfer.TransferJob.Status.ENABLED,
        'schedule': {
            'schedule_start_date': start_time_schedule,
            'schedule_end_date': end_time_schedule
        }...
```

The format of 'schedule_start_date' and 'schedule_end_date' above is:
{'day': 19, 'month': 4, 'year': 2023}
{'day': 10, 'month': 5, 'year': 2023}

Comment: Have you checked this [scheduling options](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#:~:text=Choose%20your%20scheduling%20options%3A) wherein you can select to run every week? You can check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzGHI.png) for your reference. Let me know what happens when you select this option.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am configuring it by referring to the scheduling options above, but I am not configuring it in the console, but through the Python SDK. In the code, I pass in the parameters by the following way, but the final generated task is DAILY no matter how I configure it.

Comment: Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#client-libraries:~:text=client%20libraries.-,Transfer%20between%20Cloud%20Storage%20buckets,-In%20this%20example), you should include `object_conditions` for Python to include duration on how often the transfer will occur.